# How does the Pyromancer achievement work?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

In Team Fortress 2, I was checking the Pyro achievements and I noticed that my progress for Pyromancer shows 0/1,000,000 points of fire damage, even though I know for a fact that I have dealt fire damage. Am I making progress that the UI does not show, or is setting enemies on fire with the flamethrower not enough to get the achievement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To this day, it appears to still not be working from around early November 2011. Even looking at the achievement through Steam, [as suggested here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2233603), didn't show the numbers. It is, however, possible to see the progress tracked through the game's HUD.

While in game: menu -> view achievements, and there will be a box you can tick that says **show in HUD** next to the pyromancer achievement.

I can personally say I've gotten Pyromancer in the past year, past November 2011, and it does show mine at 1,000,000 while in game.

Comment: So, I checked in game, and the view achievements screen shows the progress.